# When I run this code on DM, I want to get the user role on my server

Tags: python, discord, python-3.7

I know I need to use the server ID, but I don't know how to use the code

```
if message.content.startswith("!role"):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(ruleth))
        def check(msg):
            return msg.author == message.author and msg.channel == msg.channel

        try:
            msg = await client.wait_for("message", timeout=10, check=check)
        except:
            await message.channel.send("time out")
            return
        
        if random.choice(ruleth) == "text 1":
            if msg.content == "text!":
                await message.channel.send("ok!")
                member = message.author
                role = get(member.guild.roles, name="user")
                await member.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to add a role to a server via a dm to the bot if this is what you are trying to achieve due to the way the discord api works. You will have to do it in the server itself and you could run a check like

```
if msg.guild.id == yourServerID:
      await msg.author.add_role(role)
else:
     do stuff
```